# simple PHP AJAX : How to call a php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to get my javascript function to use ajax to call a php script. The php script will update a MYSQL table but I've tested the PHP script and it works fine.

This is my function:

```
    function rate()
{

 $.ajax({
    data: '' ,       
    url: 'update.php',
    method: 'GET', 
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});

}
```

and the function is called later with:

```
rate();
```

The php script doesn't need any information given to it, it just needs to be called, can anyone point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Learning to use the *Network* tab in modern browsers is going to aid you significantly with AJAX.

Comment: the script does not run

Comment: firefox, install firebug module and check in the console what's wrong

Comment: Does the url exist? If not, the 'success' function will never be called. I also recommend to install firebug (Maxime). Your code should work.

Comment: What is the error in console.? which script is not running the ajax script or the PHP script..? I am not clear here.

Answer (score 1):

Just use like in this example:

```
<script>
  function rate() {
    $.get("update.php");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand sorry, this would go instead of the rate function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I use the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: "page_url",
                               dataType: 'json',
                               data: {
                                   'date1' : date1,
                                   'call': 'function_name'
                               },
                               beforeSend: function(){
                                   $("#loading").show();
                               },
                               success : function(response){    
                                  },
                                complete: function(){ 
                                   $("#loading").hide();
                               }
                      })
```

and on php part I add:

```
function function_name($request){
  your code here
}

if (!empty($_POST['call'])) {
    die($_POST['call']($_POST));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to pass the data to the PHP page, you can omit 'Data' from the ajax parameters.

```
<script>
    function rate(){
        $.ajax({      
            url: 'update.php',
            method: 'POST', 
            success: function(msg) {
               alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    rate();
</script>
```

Comment: That's true, but isn't relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included `jquery` library
Try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
      function rate()
{

 $.ajax({
    data: '' ,       
    url: 'update.php',
    method: 'GET', 
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});

}


    rate();


</script>
```

Comment: How does waiting for the DOM to load affect this?

Answer (score 0):

i show my all working code, try it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      function rate() {
        $.get("update.php");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="rate()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```